# Bind datas in ember

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-binding, ember.js

I have an datas array with some objects :

```
dataArray: [
    {name: 'n1', b: 2, c: 3},
    {name: 'n2', b: 5, c: 6},
    {name: 'n3', b: 8, c: 9}
]
```

I initilize it empty `dataArray: Ember.A([])` and push datas in this object with `pushObject( Ember.Object.create( dataItem ) )`

And a complex nested array where each of my objects can appear zero or multiple times. This array is loaded from a server and used for display purpose in a template. It can looks like that :

```
displayedArray: [
    [
        {name: 'n2'},
        {name: 'n3'},
        [
            {name: 'n1'},
            {name: 'n2'},
            {name: 'n3'},
        ]
    ]
    {name: 'n3'},
    {name: 'n1'}
]
```

The key / value pairs of each objects in my datas array is updated after async callas to a server. I need to update all the objects in my display array when my data object is updated by injecting / deleting or updating the key / value pairs.

I think I should use something like that : http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/bindings/

But I cannot figure out how to use it in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you store your data in ember objects and follow the ember get/set paradigm, then all changes on your data will be reflected to your template. For example,

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/OMItuCiN/1

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    <h2>Welcome to Ember.js</h2>

    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  {{#if data}}
    <ul>
    {{#each item in data}}
      <li>{{item.name}}</li>
    {{/each}}
    </ul>
    <button {{action 'update'}}>update data</button>
    {{else}}
    loading....
    {{/if}}
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Router.map(function() {
  // put your routes here
});

App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController:function(controller,model){
    asyncUpdate(controller);
  }
});

App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  data:[],
  actions:{
    update:function(){
      this.set('data',[]);
      asyncUpdate(this);
    }
  }
  /*namedEntities:function(){
    return data;
  }.property('data.@each.name')*/
});

App.NamedEntity =  Ember.Object.extend({
  name:null
});

function asyncUpdate(controller){
  /*get data from server*/
    setTimeout(function(){
      var data=[];
      var dataFromServer = '[{"name": "n'+Math.round(Math.random()*10)+'", "b": 2, "c": 3},{"name": "n'+Math.round(Math.random()*10)+'", "b": 5, "c": 6},{"name": "n'+Math.round(Math.random()*10)+'", "b": 8, "c": 9}]';
      JSON.parse(dataFromServer).forEach(function(namedEntity){
        data.pushObject(App.NamedEntity.create({name:namedEntity.name}));
      });
      controller.set('data',data);
    },2000);
}
```

If you have a complex structure of data you need to accomodate that in ember object relationships.

In your case if you turn your data to a simple array, as I think you have already done, then the example above should help. Otherwise if your arrays belong in different groups then try to create ember objects representing these groups containing array of children ember objects and so on.

Comment: Your answer is a good one, but not to my question. Display and update my `dataArray` is not a problem. It has been created as an ember array so any updates in the array are automatically binded to the template. The thing I want to do is bind elements of a nested array to the elements of this `dataArray`.

Comment: @fabien is it possible to place the elements of your nested array inside ember objects and then push these in arrays that are properties of your outer array? If yes then the changes of your data will also reflect automatically.

Comment: @fabien for example http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ItEmAgiT/1/edit , of course you may have some logic dictating your data structure. If the objects within your data structure have some relation and need to be bound to aggregate data with each other have a look in guides http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/. If i'm off track please assist so i can help you more accurately, thanks.

Comment: Actually, both elements are from the server. First, I get dataArray (the datas) ; and then displayedArray (the way I have to display them). And finally, I fill every objects of displayedArray with the datas from dataArray. For now I'm on holyday :) but I'll edit your fiddle when I'm back. But you need a recursive template to display properly the displayedArray.

Comment: @fabien i think i get a better picture now.I will not analyse the structure that you will be building,since this is straightforward based on your requirements.I focused on your demand to display this hierarchical structure of ember objects and prepared an example with recursion http://emberjs.jsbin.com/unUpEqEM/1/edit don't pay much attention to this example's data structure. This is based on a similar requirement another user had, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20797738/ember-js-generate-html-from-json-with-iteration/20801586#20801586 . Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

BTW, if you have the same problem and no solution, here's how I make it work for now :

I have an update function like this :

```
update: function() {
    var self = this;

    var runUpdate = function( target ) {
        _.each(target, function(item){
            if( Ember.typeOf( target ) === array ) {
              runUpdate(item);
            }
            else {
                item.setProperties( _.findWhere( self.get('dataArray'), {name: item.name} ) );
            }
    }
    runUpdate( self.get('displayedArray') );
}
```

This is just a recursive function to update every objects in the nested array from their source in the data array (_.each and _.findWhere are from lodash because I(m used to it, but ember has pretty much the same utilities)